# Remove a Control from View

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a sap.m.Text at runtime and remove the created element. Creation is straight forward but deleting the elements is a problem. I couldn't find a way to do it.

Code :

Create
new sap.m.Text(this.createId("Row1"))

Remove

```
_oThis.getView().removeContent(1); // Doesn't work
_oThis.getView().removeContent(oObjText); // Doesn't work
_oThis.getView().removeContent(sap.ui.getCore().byId('Row1')); // Doesn't work
_oThis.getView().removeContent(view.byId(oo));   // Doesn't work
_oThis.getView().removeContent('Row1');   // Doesn't work
```

The thing that removes the element os $('Row1').remove(); // But doesn't remove from aggregation and gives a duplicate ID error if added back with same ID 'Row1'

PS : 
$('Row1').remove() doesn't truly work as its not deleted from view object. How to remove a Text/Button or any control from JS View by ID ?

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html#removeContent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a small local example on my local machine. You have two options, either to check at creation time whether your text control already exists and just do some adjustments or - if you really want to have a clean start - to destroy it:

```
this.byId("Row1").destroy();
```

Note, that it's best practice to create identifier by using createId:

```
this.createId("Row1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the control using the `.destroy<aggregationName>()` method.

For example, `sap/f/DynamicPage` has an aggregation named `<content>`. I.e. [`.destroyContent()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.f.DynamicPage#methods/destroyContent) can be used:

```js
var oDynamicPage = this.byId("dynamicContentForm");
if (oDynamicPage !== undefined) {
  oDynamicPage.destroyContent();
}
```